# Do spark plugs need changing if one ignition coil cable broke

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, renault, ignition-coil

A friend of mine had one of their ignition coil snap in half, which meant one cylinder wasn't firing. She drove for approximately for 10km, before getting back home and finding out what was wrong.

We will be replacing the cables tomorrow, and I was wondering would we need to change the spark plugs too? Or would they not be damaged enough to prompt a change?

The car is Renault modus 1.2 2009.

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect on the plugs at all. The one in the non-firing cylinder might have had some unburnt fuel on it, but that won't cause any damage.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

No, you'd not necessarily need to change out spark plugs. The single plug may have some fuel build up on it, but as soon as it starts firing again, it should be okay. If it isn't, then change it at that time (my bet is on it will be just fine).

You shouldn't need to change out plugs but at the recommended service level. That said, if you're close enough to that mileage, you might want to think about it. If you're not anywhere close to it, just *run what yah brung*.